# Shopify Adding Image in Rich text box shows broken image after adding

Tags: schema, shopify, liquid

I am attempting to add new block in Shopify using schema and Shopify liquid. I have added schema which is expected to add/import image one on left side and one for right side.I have created dynamic block just to show both images. When I added my schema , I am able to see the image rich text box to add images but when I add the images, I get them as broken images and when I inspect them in in browser i just get `<img src=/>`.I am quite close but something missing here.Is there something wrong with `<img src={{settings.block.image}} />` ? Thanks.

Custom Block

```
 {% elsif block.type == 'side_by_side' %}

<div class="homepage_content clearfix" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="eight columns image_column">
      <img src={{settings.block.image}} /> 
    </div>
    <div class="eight columns image_column">
      <img src={{settings.block.image}} /> 
    </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Schema

```
   {
      "type": "side_by_side",
      "name": "side_by_side",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image-left",
          "label": "Image-left"
        },
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image-right",
          "label": "Image-right"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "layout",
          "label": "Layout",
          "default": "left",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "left",
              "label": "Image on left"
            },
            {
              "value": "right",
              "label": "Image on right"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "title",
          "label": "Heading",
          "default": "Side by Side Engineering "
        },
        {
          "type": "richtext",
          "id": "text",
          "label": "Text",
          "default": "<p>Pair text with an image to give focus to your chosen product, collection, or blog post. Add details on availability, style, or even provide a review.</p>"
        },
        {
          "type": "select",
          "id": "text_alignment",
          "label": "Text alignment",
          "options": [
            {
              "value": "left",
              "label": "Left"
            },
            {
              "value": "center",
              "label": "Center"
            },
            {
              "value": "right",
              "label": "Right"
            }
          ],
          "default": "left"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "id": "button_label",
          "label": "Button label"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "button_link",
          "label": "Button link"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All images must include `img_url` in order for them to grab the CDN path to the image itself.

In addition you must target the block image this way `block.settings.image` not `settings.block.image`.

So your code should be `{{ block.settings.image-left | img_url: '1024x' }}` or the size you like it to be.

Comment: <div class="eight columns image_column">
             {% capture image_layout %}
                <div class="eight columns image_column {% if block.settings.layout == 'left' %}alpha{% else %}omega{% endif %}">
                  {% if block.settings.image-left != blank %}
                    {{ block.settings.image-left | img_url: '1024x' }}
                  {% else %}
                    {{ 'image' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
             {% endcapture %} I added like this but now its not even showing broken Images

Comment: You will need to debug your code. I don't know what's going with the rest of it. For example you are capturing the code, but are you outputting the capture itself? Consider reading the Shopify docs, because from what I can see you don't understand the logic behind sections and how to use filters properly. Check if you are entering your `if` statement, `console.log` the results from each object and debug the code, that's how it's done.

Comment: Since it is liquid how can I check is it entering into `if` condition ? and which value to be `console.log` ?

Comment: Your  snippet actually works , I just have to enclose this into image tag and it worked.